# No qualifying bean of type is defined [duplicated]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Currently I experiencing the BeanNameAware interface are not working if AOP is implementing in my Knight Bean.

Why is this happening? because of CGLib conflict? For reference I am using spring framework 3

here is my bean code

```
public class BraveKnight implements BeanNameAware{
    private Quest quest;

    public void setQuest(Quest mockQuest){
        this.quest = mockQuest;
    }

    public void embarkOnQuest(){
        quest.embark();
    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        System.out.println(beanName +" bean has been initialized..." ); 
    }
}
```

Application context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="knight" class="com.springinaction.knights.BraveKnight">
        <property name="quest" > <ref bean="quest"/> </property>
    </bean>     

    <bean id="quest" class="com.springinaction.knights.Quest">
        <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}" />        
    </bean>

    <bean id="minstrel" class="com.springinaction.knights.Minstrel">
        <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}" />        
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
            <aop:pointcut id="embark" expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))" />

            <aop:before pointcut-ref="embark" method="singBeforeQuest" />

            <aop:after pointcut-ref="embark" method="singAfterQuest" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

**[Edit 1]:** and here is my main class, I tried getBean with string and class but seems no big differences

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 
   AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/web/*.xml"); 
   BraveKnight knight = context.getBean(BraveKnight.class); 
   knight.embarkOnQuest(); 
   context.close(); 
}
```

and my result is getting these errors so I am suspecting CGLib conflict with Spring AOP?

```
quest bean has been initialized...
knight bean has been initialized...
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.springinaction.knights.BraveKnight] is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1125)
    at com.springinaction.knights.KnightMain.main(KnightMain.java:10)
```

Comment: Show your main class as well. Something's fishy, and it looks like there may be a problem with your explicit `getBean()` call.

Comment: Edit the question to add the code there instead of in a comment. Additionally, turn up logging for the Spring Framework to DEBUG and post the log output here. As a debugging step, try adding `context.refresh()` after you create it.

Comment: no effect to the errors, after I add up `context.refresh()` right after `getBean()`

Comment: i had switch my spring framework version from 3.2.4 to 4.2.1 and it work just what expected, as a conclude, CGLIB-based proxy classes no longer require a default constructor in spring 4 with this source explained > [link](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/07/spring-4-cglib-based-proxy-classes-with-no-default-ctor.html) thanks for you effort @chrylis

Comment: As long as you're going with modern Spring, I recommend using Spring Boot. It eliminates most of the boilerplate here (though you'd still have to specify configuration somehow if you're wanting to wire something like `System.out` in as a bean parameter).